# Unable to execute c executable files on initramfs x86_64

Tags: c, linux

I am using an embedded board with initramfs, i am trying to execute c files on x86_64 based board.

When i try to execute a simple hello world program, it is giving **sh: ./hello: not found error**,
Using `gcc hello.c --static -o hello`,  all is working well.

Now I have another c file which depends on libpthread (pthread functions) and librt

If I try to compile using `gcc pthread.c -o pthread -lpthread -lrt` the result is **sh: ./pthread: not found**

I cannot use `--static` option here, because as it depends on dynamic libraries.

Comment: So you have answered your own question. You don't have the dynamic libraries, or the system is incapable of dynamic linking. Either compile it statically, or set your system up properly.

Comment: Then install required dynamic libs into your target `/usr/lib` or `/lib` dir.